# Runtime error, possible input problem?

Tags: c++

I have a book class that takes title, author, copyright, ISBN number, and checkout for a book object. However, I'm getting a runtime error when the program runs. After the user inputs the title and presses enter, the program skips down, showing the rest of the outputs, and then terminates the program giving a runtime error.

I tried to catch an exception, but I didn't get anything.

Code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Book{
public:
       string what_title();
       string what_author();
       int what_copyright();
       void store_ISBN();
       void is_checkout();
private:
        char check;
        int ISBNfirst, ISBNsecond, ISBNthird;
        char ISBNlast;
        string title;
        string author;
        int copyright;
};

string Book::what_title()
{
       cout << "Title: ";
       cin >> title;
       cout << endl;
       return title;
}

string Book::what_author()
{
       cout << "Author: ";
       cin >> author;
       cout << endl;
       return author;
}

int Book::what_copyright()
{
    cout << "Copyright Year: ";
    cin >> copyright;
    cout << endl;
    return copyright;
}

void Book::store_ISBN()
{
     bool test = false;
     cout << "Enter ISBN number separated by spaces: ";
     while(!test){
     cin >> ISBNfirst >> ISBNsecond >> ISBNthird >> ISBNlast;
     if((ISBNfirst || ISBNsecond || ISBNthird)<0 || (ISBNfirst || ISBNsecond || ISBNthird)>9)
                   error("Invalid entry.");
     else if(!isdigit(ISBNlast) || !isalpha(ISBNlast))
          error("Invalid entry.");
     else test = true;}     
}

void Book::is_checkout()
{
     bool test = false;
     cout << "Checked out?(Y or N): ";
     while(!test){
     cin >> check;
     if(check = 'Y') test = true;
     else if(check = 'N') test = true;                                
     else error("Invalid value.");}
}

int main()
{
    Book one;
    one.what_title();
    one.what_author();
    one.what_copyright();
    one.store_ISBN();
    one.is_checkout();
    keep_window_open();
}
```

Not sure what the problem could be. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Output example:

Title: One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest
(next lines aren't actually spaced in between and all output at once)
Author:

Copyright Year:

Enter ISBN number separated by spaces:

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact support for more information.

Also don't worry about the keep_window_open and error functions. They are part of the std_lib_facilities.h and are most likely not causing the problem. Error just outputs an error message if a problem is encountered.

Comment: what's keep_window_open?

Comment: How about showing all the necessary code (as Alex suggests, keep_window_open), and also showing the input/output of your program so we can see exactly what gets printed and where it fails.

Comment: I just did a quick google of std_lib_facilities.h and it is for a course... it has a function keep_window_open: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: Okay. Keep_window_open is part of the std_lib_facilities header which is very long. All it does is the trick to wait for input of a character so the window doesn't close automatically when you run the progam. I will add in the output in a second.

Comment: And it's technically not homework since I'm self learning, but okay.

Comment: What is the Operating System?

Comment: The Operating System is Vista.

Comment: He is clearly using a header file including in a programming book or online tutorial for the sake of making things as portable as possible. The function "keep_window_open" is, by my best guess, a function which calls system("pause") on Windows, and does nothing on all other operating systems.

Comment: Just realized that the title function is only taking a one word string, so the other inputs for the title are going into the next functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the C++ input streams do not remove malformatted input that they encounter. In other words if you try to read in a number and the stream contains, for example the character 'x' (not a number), that character isn't removed from the input stream. Additionally, if I remember correctly, that will also put the input stream in an error state causing well-formatted input to also fail. Although there is a mechanism for testing the state of the input stream and removing malformattted input and clearing the error flags, I have personally found it simpler to always read into a string  (using ">>" or "getline") and then to parse the string. In the case of a number, for example, you can use the "strtol" or "strtoul" functions.

Comment: Yeah I was sitting here thinking and realized that it's only taking the "The" of the string and using the other inputs for the next functions. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Yup getline worked! Just needed a push in the right direction, thanks.